# how to fix background color in hashtags.js in textarea

Tags: jquery, css

Please see demo :

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Facebook-Like-Hashtag-Highlighting-Plugin-with-jQuery-hashtags-js/

When I type hastag : #AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

background not follow new line in textarea . That mean it only first line. How to fixed it.

I don't know fix it in jquery file or css file . Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: can you attach your source code?

Comment: I only find this demo . I am looking for best js hashtag. But I see not working exactly. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @QuocHuy, #AAA... work well. you click on enter for new line?

Comment: short answer: change from `textarea` to `contentEditable` element

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution to your problem. As I couldn't find the cdn of hashtags js and css file, I have directly linked to github code. You can download the js and css file locally or use npm and link it your page to use it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("textarea").hashtags();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.autosize/3.0.20/autosize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/lookapanda/jquery-hashtags/master/css/jquery.hashtags.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/lookapanda/jquery-hashtags/master/js/jquery.hashtags.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" autofocus>
</textarea>
```

Comment: I try your demo and when I type #AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA background not follow enter new line.

Comment: Do you mean it's not getting blue colored?

Comment: You can type as below you see background color hashtag not exactly

Comment: #AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 

#bbbbbbbbbbbbb
#bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

Comment: Yes Hassan Imam

Comment: Copy the line and paste in textarea and then press any key from keyboard it will work.

Comment: Dear Hassan Imam you can copy #AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA‌​AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA #bbbbbbbbbbbbb #bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb and you try in code snippet you will see it wrong

Comment: If you are wondering why part of #AAA text is not getting blue colored then you will find a linebreak in the text. So, it is not highlighting after that. Remove that character and it will highlight the whole string.

Comment: Google Chrome working as well , but Firefox working wong

Comment: Yes, you are right, firefox is not working properly. You should find some other alternative for this.